# JTAppleCalendar cell background color change error in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, calendar, jtapplecalendar

Im using `JTAppleCalendar` in my project you can see it here ->  https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar. But when I want to change background colors in some cells gives me big problem , when I past previous and next months some cells background colors changing ?

> How it is possible ? How can I fix it ?  I want to change only; Example ;

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"Mains")
let predicate = NSPredicate (format:"date = %@",freshdate)
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

if let result = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Mains] {
    for object in result {
        if(object.user! == "" < freshdate) {
           cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "f7bca6")
        } else if(object.userme! == "") {
           cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "f7bca6")
        } else {
           cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "ffffff")
       }
    }
}
```

Ones , but when I turn another month , in calendar looking some cells backgrounds changed.

Under below picture shows true when app opened.

[image]

But when I past previous or next month changed some cells backgrounds under below. This is mistake. I don't want to change thats.

[image]

My codes under below , where I can mistake ?

```
@IBOutlet weak var calendarView: JTAppleCalendarView!
let kStartDate = "2016-01-01"
let kEndDate = "2049-12-31"
var numberOfRows = 6
let formatter = DateFormatter()
var myCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
var generateInDates: InDateCellGeneration = .forAllMonths
var generateOutDates: OutDateCellGeneration = .off
var hasStrictBoundaries = true
let firstDayOfWeek: DaysOfWeek = .monday
var monthSize: MonthSize? = nil

extension ViewController: JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate, JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource {
   func configureCalendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView) -> ConfigurationParameters {
      formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
      formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
      formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")

      let startDate = formatter.date(from: kStartDate)!
      let endDate = formatter.date(from: kEndDate)!      
      let parameters = ConfigurationParameters(startDate: startDate,
                                                     endDate: endDate,
                                                     numberOfRows: numberOfRows,
                                                     calendar: myCalendar,
                                                     generateInDates: generateInDates,
                                                     generateOutDates: generateOutDates,
                                                     firstDayOfWeek: firstDayOfWeek,
                                                     hasStrictBoundaries: hasStrictBoundaries)
      return parameters
   }

   func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) -> JTAppleCell {
        let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellView", for: indexPath) as! CellView
        let comedate = String(describing: myCalendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: cellState.date))
        var freshdate = comedate.substring(from: 9)
        freshdate = freshdate.substring(to: 10)

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"Mains")
        let predicate = NSPredicate (format:"date = %@",freshdate)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        if let result = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Mains] {
            for object in result {
                if(object.user! == "" < freshdate) {
                   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "f7bca6")
                } else if(object.userme! == "") {
                   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "f7bca6")
                } else {
                   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "ffffff")
                }
            }
        }

        handleCellConfiguration(cell: cell, cellState: cellState)
        return cell
   }
}
```

Comment: @ Any idea? I try everything but same problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved issue just I used ;

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = nil
```

before;

```
 if let result = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Mains] {
            for object in result {
                if(object.user! == "" < freshdate) {
                   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "f7bca6")
                } else if(object.userme! == "") {
                   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "f7bca6")
                } else {
                   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "ffffff")
                }
            }
        }
```

And which cell item you want to change color, title, etc.. just add before **= nil**

After worked, I think will help many people.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's reuse cell issue, you can try set default background color.

```
if freshdate == "2017-04-16" {
   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "f7bca6")
} else if freshdate == "2017-04-28" {
   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "45ca6")
} else {
   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "your_color")
}
```

Comment: dude for static if else ones working but I m using it  for object in result in core data and have many cells background color change and at time app doing mistake

Comment: I added core data codes , updated question you can see there

Comment: I've been struggling with this for hours, it was just a problem of reuse cell. **THANK YOU**

Answer (score 0):

As [@Quoc Le](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4033861/) says, it is a cell reuse issue. But there is also another issue here.

This function is called for every cell on the screen. So in a nutshell here is the problem that is happening.

```
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) -> JTAppleCell {

    // Here you got one single cell
    let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellView", for: indexPath) as! CellView

    // Here you got a result for your single cell
    if let result = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Mains] {

         // Here you are changing the color of a *single* cell multiple times
         // Based on the number of [objects] found in the [result]
         // Why?
         for object in result {
            if(object.user! == "" < freshdate) {
               cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "f7bca6")
            } else if(object.userme! == "") {
               cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "f7bca6")
            } else {
               cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "ffffff")
            }
        }
    } else { 
         // There will also be a problem here if you data is not found.
         // Your cell background color will just pick up any random re-used color
    }
}
```

What you should do is have your `DataSource` already prepared.
Here is an example:

```
let myDataSource: [Mains] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Load the data source
    myDataSource = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Mains]
}
```

Now, Based on what value in your data source, do you want to change a cell's background color?
It looks like you are checking for `object.user`, `object.userme` and `empty value`

Looks like you are checking for arbitrary data.

The `cellForItemAt date: Date` function maps a cell to a **Date**, not arbitrary data. 
Therefore you must map your DataSource to a Date. This can be done with a `Dictionary`. Therefore change you DataSource to look something like this:

```
let myDataSource: [String: Mains ] = [:]
// The String can be a date string
// The Mains object can be the object associated with that Date
```

now your `cellForItem` function can look like this:

```
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) -> JTAppleCell {

    // Here you got one single cell
    let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellView", for: indexPath) as! CellView

    // Here you got a result for your single cell
    let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFrom(date)
    let myObjectForThisCell = myDataSource[dateString]

    if(myObjectForThisCell.user! == "" < freshdate) {
       cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "f7bca6")
    } else if(myObjectForThisCell.userme! == "") {
       cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "f7bca6")
    } else {
       cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex:  "ffffff")
    }
}
```

The code I have pasted above is incomplete. But hopefully you get the idea of how you should set this up. The problem you are having is not a calendar problem. It a problem of how a normal `UICollectionView` or `UITableView` works.

Comment: @JtAppleCanedar for iOS Swift ty man but don't worked I added example project codes https://github.com/codeservis/ExampleCalendar. you can download zip file and you can look it. don't shows some cells background change .

Comment: also when I turning left , right, left right many times mixing everything.